# NotificationListenerService not working in MIUI 9 based system

Tags: java, android, android-notifications, notification-listener, miui

I have a simple NotificationListenerService setup.

It is working in Android 6 / 7 in other phones. It used to work in Android 6 in MIUI based system. But it does not work in MIUI 9 which is Android 7.

What is the issue?

```
public class MyNotification extends NotificationListenerService {
    Context context;

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {

        super.onCreate();
        context = getApplicationContext();

    }


    /*
        These are the package names of the apps. for which we want to
        listen the notifications
     */
    private static final class ApplicationPackageNames {
        public static final String FACEBOOK_PACK_NAME = "com.facebook.katana";
        public static final String FACEBOOK_MESSENGER_PACK_NAME = "com.facebook.orca";
        public static final String WHATSAPP_PACK_NAME = "com.whatsapp";
        public static final String INSTAGRAM_PACK_NAME = "com.instagram.android";
    }

    /*
        These are the return codes we use in the method which intercepts
        the notifications, to decide whether we should do something or not
     */
    public static final class InterceptedNotificationCode {
        public static final int FACEBOOK_CODE = 1;
        public static final int WHATSAPP_CODE = 2;
        public static final int INSTAGRAM_CODE = 3;
        public static final int OTHER_NOTIFICATIONS_CODE = 4; // We ignore all notification with code == 4
    }

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return super.onBind(intent);
    }

    @Override
    public void onNotificationPosted(StatusBarNotification sbn){

        String packageName = sbn.getPackageName();
        String ticker ="";
        if(sbn.getNotification().tickerText !=null) {
            ticker = sbn.getNotification().tickerText.toString();
        }
        Bundle extras = sbn.getNotification().extras;
        String title = extras.getString("android.title");
        String text = extras.getCharSequence("android.text").toString();

        Log.i("Package",packageName);
        Log.i("Ticker",ticker);
        Log.i("Title",title);
        Log.i("Text",text);

        Intent intent = new  Intent("com.arjun.mynotification");
        intent.putExtra("packageName", packageName);
        intent.putExtra("title", title);

        LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(context).sendBroadcast(intent);

    }

    @Override
    public void onNotificationRemoved(StatusBarNotification sbn){
        int notificationCode = matchNotificationCode(sbn);

        if(notificationCode != InterceptedNotificationCode.OTHER_NOTIFICATIONS_CODE) {

            StatusBarNotification[] activeNotifications = this.getActiveNotifications();

            if(activeNotifications != null && activeNotifications.length > 0) {
                for (int i = 0; i < activeNotifications.length; i++) {
                    if (notificationCode == matchNotificationCode(activeNotifications[i])) {
                        Intent intent = new  Intent("com.arjun.mynotification");
                        intent.putExtra("Notification Code", notificationCode);
                        LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(context).sendBroadcast(intent);
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    private int matchNotificationCode(StatusBarNotification sbn) {
        String packageName = sbn.getPackageName();

        if(packageName.equals(ApplicationPackageNames.FACEBOOK_PACK_NAME)
                || packageName.equals(ApplicationPackageNames.FACEBOOK_MESSENGER_PACK_NAME)){
            return(InterceptedNotificationCode.FACEBOOK_CODE);
        }
        else if(packageName.equals(ApplicationPackageNames.INSTAGRAM_PACK_NAME)){
            return(InterceptedNotificationCode.INSTAGRAM_CODE);
        }
        else if(packageName.equals(ApplicationPackageNames.WHATSAPP_PACK_NAME)){
            return(InterceptedNotificationCode.WHATSAPP_CODE);
        }
        else{
            return(InterceptedNotificationCode.OTHER_NOTIFICATIONS_CODE);
        }
    }

}
```

Manifest.xml

```
<service android:name=".MyNotification"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:permission="android.permission.BIND_NOTIFICATION_LISTENER_SERVICE">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.service.notification.NotificationListenerService" />
        </intent-filter>
</service>
```

The ADB logs doesn't return anything to suggest what is the issue?
Neither I could find much in other places to proceed with an investigation.

Comment: Hi bro, could you find an answer for this?

Comment: Any workaround found ?

Answer (score 0):

Have you enabled notification service for your app?

```
private boolean isNotificationServiceEnabled(){
    String pkgName = getPackageName();
    final String flat = Settings.Secure.getString(getContentResolver(),
            ENABLED_NOTIFICATION_LISTENERS);
    if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(flat)) {
        final String[] names = flat.split(":");
        for (int i = 0; i < names.length; i++) {
            final ComponentName cn = ComponentName.unflattenFromString(names[i]);
            if (cn != null) {
                if (TextUtils.equals(pkgName, cn.getPackageName())) {
                    return true;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return false;
}


private AlertDialog buildNotificationServiceAlertDialog(){
    AlertDialog.Builder alertDialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    alertDialogBuilder.setTitle(R.string.notification_listener_service);
    alertDialogBuilder.setMessage(R.string.notification_listener_service_explanation);
    alertDialogBuilder.setPositiveButton(R.string.yes,
            new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                    startActivity(new Intent(ACTION_NOTIFICATION_LISTENER_SETTINGS));
                }
            });
    alertDialogBuilder.setNegativeButton(R.string.no,
            new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                    // If you choose to not enable the notification listener
                    // the app. will not work as expected
                }
            });
    return(alertDialogBuilder.create());
}
}
```

Comment: Yes it is enabled. The app works in other Android 7 based phones normally.